# "Standard Notes" wont launch (on Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, snap-store

I installed Standard Notes on Kubuntu 22.10 but it won't launch. The symbol briefly appears in the task bar but then vanishes again. It worked on a previous installation of Kubuntu 22.10 but I had to do a fresh install because I wasnt happy with my partitioning.

I installed the latest version of Standard Notes with `sudo snap install standard-notes` as it is provided in the snap store.

Any pointers how I could find out why it doesnt work anymore?

Comment: Is it possible that the one that worked was not a snap install?

Comment: I dont think so but of course cant completely rule that out.